# Google Assistant and Dialogflow requests Quotas

Tags: actions-on-google

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas) Google Assistant requests to the Dialogflow (Standard Edition) have the following limits: **180 requests per minute**.
I'm developing a Google Assistant action which is a quite interactive. For a single user it may take calling up to 10 Intents (requests) / per minute. Are we really saying that based on that limits my Assistant action won't be able to handle more than 18 users' sessions per minute? Really?
What if you have more than 10 000 daily active users? How about 100 000 or even more DAU?

The Google Assistant Conversational Actions documentation is silent about it. It would be great if somebody from Google Assistant team could clarify it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I posted similar question about request quotas for Action Builder on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/mpaosb/quota_request_for_action_builder/).
According to the reply, there is no such thing as quota for Assistant Actions built with Actions Builder and the only limitation is your backend capacity e.g. Firebase or another implementation.

Also, I found a comment about 400k users by month in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/law9ta/google_actions_console_pricing/).

It would be great if someone from Google Assistant representatives can confirm this or add a section to the official documentation. Because this would help to invest in developing new google actions on enterprise level without a fear to bump into request limitations.